# Libgdx Jiggering Sprite Movement

Tags: java, libgdx, sprite, flappy-bird-clone

I recently got into LibGDX using the book "LibGDX Game Development By Example" (Pretty good one btw) and have been playing around with the tutorial projects for the last month.

One of these games is a FlappyBird-clone (of course it is) and I decided to add features, change sprites etc.

Now the problem is that the normal obstacle graphics (flowers) don't fit the new theme and need to be exchanged.
Doing so results in jiggering graphics for the new sprites.

I should point out that the code used to visualize these obstacles has not changed at all, simply exchanging the sprites causes this problem.
I tried a lot of different sprites and all that are not identical to the flowers seem to have this problem.

So whatever is the cause, the old flower sprites are unaffected, every other sprite is.

On to the code (Removed some Getters/Setters and other unrelated methods)

The Flower/Obstacle Class:

```
public class Flower
{

    private static final float COLLISION_RECTANGLE_WIDTH = 13f;
    private static final float COLLISION_RECTANGLE_HEIGHT = 447f;
    private static final float COLLISION_CIRCLE_RADIUS = 33f;

    private float x = 0;
    private float y = 0;

    private static final float MAX_SPEED_PER_SECOND = 100f;
    public static final float WIDTH = COLLISION_CIRCLE_RADIUS * 2;
    private static final float HEIGHT_OFFSET = -400.0f;

    private static final float DISTANCE_BETWEEN_FLOOR_AND_CEILING = 225.0f;
    private final Circle floorCollisionCircle;
    private final Rectangle floorCollisionRectangle;
    private final Circle ceilingCollisionCircle;
    private final Rectangle ceilingCollisionRectangle;
    private boolean pointClaimed = false;

    private final TextureRegion floorTexture;
    private final TextureRegion ceilingTexture;


    float textureX,textureY;


    public Flower(TextureRegion floorTexture, TextureRegion ceilingTexture)
    {
        this.floorTexture = floorTexture;
        this.ceilingTexture = ceilingTexture;
        this.y = MathUtils.random(HEIGHT_OFFSET);
        this.floorCollisionRectangle = new Rectangle(x,y,COLLISION_RECTANGLE_WIDTH,COLLISION_RECTANGLE_HEIGHT);
        this.floorCollisionCircle = new Circle(x + floorCollisionRectangle.width / 2, y + floorCollisionRectangle.height, COLLISION_CIRCLE_RADIUS);
        this.ceilingCollisionRectangle = new Rectangle(x,floorCollisionCircle.y + DISTANCE_BETWEEN_FLOOR_AND_CEILING,COLLISION_RECTANGLE_WIDTH,
                COLLISION_RECTANGLE_HEIGHT);
        this.ceilingCollisionCircle = new Circle(x + ceilingCollisionRectangle.width / 2, ceilingCollisionRectangle.y, COLLISION_CIRCLE_RADIUS);
    }



    public void update(float delta)
    {
        setPosition(x - (MAX_SPEED_PER_SECOND * delta));
    }

    public void setPosition(float x)
    {
        this.x = x;
        updateCollisionCircle();
        updateCollisionRectangle();
    }

    private void updateCollisionCircle()
    {
        floorCollisionCircle.setX(x + floorCollisionRectangle.width / 2);
        ceilingCollisionCircle.setX(x + ceilingCollisionRectangle.width / 2);
    }

    private void updateCollisionRectangle()
    {
        floorCollisionRectangle.setX(x);
        ceilingCollisionRectangle.setX(x);
    }

    public void draw(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        drawFloorFlower(batch);
        drawCeilingFlower(batch);
    }

    private void drawFloorFlower(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        textureX = floorCollisionCircle.x - floorTexture.getRegionWidth() / 2;
        textureY = floorCollisionRectangle.getY() + COLLISION_CIRCLE_RADIUS;
        batch.draw(floorTexture,textureX,textureY);
    }

    private void drawCeilingFlower(SpriteBatch batch)
    {
        textureX = ceilingCollisionCircle.x - ceilingTexture.getRegionWidth() / 2;
        textureY = ceilingCollisionRectangle.getY() - COLLISION_CIRCLE_RADIUS;
        batch.draw(ceilingTexture,textureX, textureY);
    }

}
```

And the GameScreen/Main Class:

```
public class GameScreen extends ScreenAdapter
{
    private static final float WORLD_WIDTH = 480;
    private static final float WORLD_HEIGHT = 640;

    private java.util.prefs.Preferences prefs;

    private int highscore;

    FlappeeBeeGame flappeeBeeGame;

    private ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private Camera camera;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Flappee flappee;
    private Flower flower;

    private Array<Flower> flowers = new Array<Flower>();
    private static final float GAP_BETWEEN_FLOWERS = 200.0f;

    private boolean gameOver = false;


    int score = 0;

    BitmapFont bitmapFont;
    GlyphLayout glyphLayout;

    private TextureRegion background;
    private TextureRegion flowerBottom;
    private TextureRegion flowerTop;
    private TextureRegion bee;
    private TextureRegion smallCloud;
    private TextureRegion lowCloud;

    private Music music_background;

    TextureAtlas textureAtlas;

    List<Cloud> activeClouds = new ArrayList<Cloud>();
    List<Cloud> cloudBarriers = new ArrayList<Cloud>();

    private float cloud_minScale = 0.6f;
    private float cloud_maxScale = 1.0f;

    private float cloud_minY, cloud_maxY;

    private float cloud_minDis, cloud_maxDis;

    private float cloud_minSpeed = 17.0f;
    private float cloud_maxSpeed = 27.0f;


    private final float barrierCloud_speed = 150.0f;

    private boolean inputBlocked = false;
    private float blockTime = 0.5f;
    private float remainingblockTime = blockTime;

    public GameScreen(FlappeeBeeGame fpg)
    {
        flappeeBeeGame = fpg;
        flappeeBeeGame.getAssetManager().load("assets/flappee_bee_assets.atlas",TextureAtlas.class);
        flappeeBeeGame.getAssetManager().finishLoading();
        textureAtlas = flappeeBeeGame.getAssetManager().get("assets/flappee_bee_assets.atlas");

        prefs = java.util.prefs.Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());

        highscore = prefs.getInt("highscore",0);

        music_background = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("assets/backgroundmusic.ogg"));
        music_background.setLooping(true);
        music_background.setVolume(0.5f);
        music_background.play();
    }

    private void createNewFlower()
    {
        Flower newFlower = new Flower(flowerBottom,flowerTop);
        newFlower.setPosition(WORLD_WIDTH + Flower.WIDTH);
        flowers.add(newFlower);
    }

    private void checkIfNewFlowerIsNeeded()
    {
        if(flowers.size == 0)
        {
            createNewFlower();
        }
        else
        {
            Flower flower = flowers.peek();
            if(flower.getX() < WORLD_WIDTH - GAP_BETWEEN_FLOWERS)
            {
                createNewFlower();
            }
        }
    }



    private void drawFlowers()
    {
        for(Flower flower : flowers)
        {
            flower.draw(batch);
        }
    }

    private void removeFlowersIfPassed()
    {
        if(flowers.size > 0)
        {
            Flower firstFlower = flowers.first();
            if(firstFlower.getX() < -Flower.WIDTH)
            {
                flowers.removeValue(firstFlower,true);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
        viewport.update(width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        super.show();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.position.set(WORLD_WIDTH / 2, WORLD_HEIGHT / 2, 0);
        camera.update();
        viewport = new FitViewport(WORLD_WIDTH,WORLD_HEIGHT, camera);
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        bitmapFont = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("assets/score_new.fnt"));
        glyphLayout = new GlyphLayout();


        background = textureAtlas.findRegion("bg");
        flowerBottom = textureAtlas.findRegion("pipeBottom");
        flowerTop = textureAtlas.findRegion("flowerTop");
        bee = textureAtlas.findRegion("bee");
        smallCloud = textureAtlas.findRegion("smallCloud");
        lowCloud = textureAtlas.findRegion("lowerCloud");
        flower = new Flower(flowerBottom,flowerTop);
        flappee = new Flappee(bee,textureAtlas);
        flappee.setPosition(WORLD_WIDTH/4,WORLD_HEIGHT/2);

        cloud_minDis = smallCloud.getRegionWidth() / 4;
        cloud_maxDis = smallCloud.getRegionWidth();

        cloud_maxY = viewport.getWorldHeight() - smallCloud.getRegionHeight()/2;
        cloud_minY = viewport.getWorldHeight() - smallCloud.getRegionHeight() * 2;



        Cloud a = generateCloud(null);
        Cloud b = generateCloud(a);
        Cloud c = generateCloud(b);
        Cloud d = generateCloud(c);
        Cloud e = generateCloud(d);

        activeClouds.add(a);
        activeClouds.add(b);
        activeClouds.add(c);
        activeClouds.add(d);
        activeClouds.add(e);

        a = new Cloud(lowCloud,batch,0,0 - lowCloud.getRegionHeight()/4,barrierCloud_speed,1.0f);
        b = new Cloud(lowCloud,batch,lowCloud.getRegionWidth(),0 - lowCloud.getRegionHeight()/4,barrierCloud_speed,1.0f);
        c = new Cloud(lowCloud,batch,lowCloud.getRegionWidth()*2,0 - lowCloud.getRegionHeight()/4,barrierCloud_speed,1.0f);

        cloudBarriers.add(a);
        cloudBarriers.add(b);
        cloudBarriers.add(c);

    }

    public Cloud generateCloud(Cloud formerCloud)
    {
        Cloud d;
        if(formerCloud == null)
        {
            float randomVal = (float)Math.random();
            d = new Cloud(smallCloud,batch,viewport.getWorldWidth(),
            (float)Math.random() * (cloud_maxY - cloud_minY) + cloud_minY,
                    randomVal * (cloud_maxSpeed-cloud_minSpeed) + cloud_minSpeed,
                    randomVal * (cloud_maxScale-cloud_minScale) + cloud_minScale);
            return d;
        }
        float randomVal = (float)Math.random();
        d = new Cloud(smallCloud,batch,formerCloud.getPosX() + ((float)
                Math.random() * (cloud_maxDis - cloud_minDis) + cloud_minDis),(float)Math.random() * (cloud_maxY - cloud_minY) + cloud_minY,
                randomVal * (cloud_maxSpeed-cloud_minSpeed) + cloud_minSpeed,
                randomVal * (cloud_maxScale-cloud_minScale) + cloud_minScale);
        return d;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        clearScreen();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
        shapeRenderer.setTransformMatrix(camera.view);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
        shapeRenderer.end();
        draw(delta);
        update(delta);
    }

    private void draw(float delta)
    {
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
        batch.setTransformMatrix(camera.view);
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(background,0,0);
        drawClouds(delta);
        drawScore();
        drawFlowers();
        //drawDebug();
        if(!gameOver)
        {
            flappee.draw(batch,delta);
        }
        drawBarrierClouds(delta);
        batch.end();
    }

    private void updateClouds(float delta)
    {
        boolean move = false;
        Cloud tmp = null;

        for(Cloud c : cloudBarriers)
        {
            c.update(delta);
            if(c.getPosX() <= -lowCloud.getRegionWidth())
            {
                tmp = c;
                move = true;
            }
        }

        if(move)
        {
            float positionX = cloudBarriers.get(cloudBarriers.size()-1).getPosX() + lowCloud.getRegionWidth();

            if(positionX < viewport.getWorldWidth())
            {
                positionX = viewport.getWorldWidth();
            }

            tmp.setPos(positionX,0 - lowCloud.getRegionHeight()/4);


            cloudBarriers.remove(tmp);
            cloudBarriers.add(tmp);

            tmp = null;
            move = false;
        }

        for(Cloud c : activeClouds)
        {
            c.update(delta);
            if(c.getPosX() <= -smallCloud.getRegionWidth())
            {
                tmp = c;
                move = true;
            }
        }

        if(move)
        {
            float randomVal = (float)Math.random();
            float positionX = activeClouds.get(activeClouds.size()-1).getPosX() + ((float)
                    Math.random() * (cloud_maxDis - cloud_minDis) + cloud_minDis);

            if(positionX < viewport.getWorldWidth())
            {
                positionX = viewport.getWorldWidth();
            }

            tmp.setPos(positionX,(float)Math.random() * (cloud_maxY - cloud_minY) + cloud_minY);

            tmp.setSpeed(randomVal * (cloud_maxSpeed  - cloud_minSpeed) + cloud_minSpeed);
            tmp.setScale(randomVal * (cloud_maxScale - cloud_minScale) + cloud_minScale);

            activeClouds.remove(tmp);
            activeClouds.add(tmp);
            move = false;
            tmp = null;
        }
    }

    private void drawBarrierClouds(float delta)
    {
        for(Cloud c : cloudBarriers)
        {
            c.render();
        }

    }

    private void drawClouds(float delta)
    {
        for(Cloud c : activeClouds)
        {
            c.render();
        }
    }


    private void clearScreen()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(Color.BLACK.r,Color.BLACK.g,Color.BLACK.b, Color.BLACK.a);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }

    private void blockFlappeeLeavingTheWorld()
    {
        flappee.setPosition(flappee.getX(), MathUtils.clamp(flappee.getY(),0,WORLD_HEIGHT));
    }

    private void updateFlowers(float delta)
    {
        for(Flower flower : flowers)
        {
            flower.update(delta);
        }
        checkIfNewFlowerIsNeeded();
        removeFlowersIfPassed();
    }

    private void update(float delta)
    {
        updateClouds(delta);

        if(!gameOver) {
            updateFlappee(delta);
            updateFlowers(delta);
            updateScore();


            if (checkForCollision())
            {
                gameOver = true;
                inputBlocked = true;
                remainingblockTime = blockTime;
                restart();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if((Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE) || Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)) && !inputBlocked)
            {
                gameOver = false;
                score = 0;
            }

            if(inputBlocked)
            {
                if(remainingblockTime > 0)
                {
                    remainingblockTime -= delta;
                }
                else
                {
                    inputBlocked = false;
                    remainingblockTime = blockTime;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private void restart()
    {
        flappee.setPosition(WORLD_WIDTH / 4, WORLD_HEIGHT / 2);
        flowers.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
    }

    private boolean checkForCollision()
    {
        for(Flower flower : flowers)
        {
            if(flower.isFlappeeColliding(flappee))
            {
                if(score > highscore)
                {
                    highscore = score;
                    prefs.putInt("highscore",highscore);
                    inputBlocked = true;
                    remainingblockTime = blockTime;
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I'd love to give you a runnable jar but I've got some problems building a working version. Let's just say a jar is out of the question for now.
What I can give you are screenshots:

[Jiggering Sprite View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71bmo.png)

[Functional Flower Sprite View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLGmC.png)

The first image shows the problem: The new sprites (which are just debug) become edgy like the top of the sprite can't compete with the speed of its lower half.
The second image shows the old sprites for comparison: They don't show any of this behaviour, even if they are longer than the one on the screenshot.

So what do you people think?
What causes this behaviour and how should I fix it?

Thanks in advance for any help, I appreciate it :)

Greetz!

EDIT:

I kind of fixed it.
When switching to another computer and running the game the issue didn't come up anymore.
Specifically I went from Debian to Windows 10 and from NVIDIA Optimus to a standard desktop AMD-Card.

If you should encounter this problem try another PC with a different OS and/or GPU.

Sadly (if you were to google this question) I can't tell you how to solve it on the first machine or what exactly caused it, but at least it shouldn't come up on anyone else's computer when you send them your project.